# Can we use github tag as dependency in package.json without npm publish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm, npm-publish

I am new to nodejs. Currently, I have a nodejs repo and released in github with tag as x.y.z but this is not published to npm. Is it possible to use x.y.z version in package.json as a dependency?

Comment: Per https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install you can install from git and GitHub in various ways. But that only works if the content of the repo is the same as the content of the package - many JS tools use some kind of transpilation, so you can't install directly from source.

Comment: Can we give github release version as a dependency?